# SQL query select client that has the most orders placed

Tags: sql

I want to select the client that has the most orders placed:

I have 2 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE customers(
customerid INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
NAME CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
address CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
city CHAR(30)NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE orders(
orderid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
customerid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
);
```

This is what i am trying to do:

```
SELECT customers.customerid, customers.name,orders.orderid, COUNT(customerid) 
AS CostumerCount 
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN orders 
ON customers.customerid=orders.orderid;
```

How can i make this?

Comment: What RDBMS is this?? Do you mean the highest orders count?

Comment: Do you need orders.orderid as a column?

Comment: No i mean The client that HAS the MOST orders placed.

Comment: not necessarily.. this is from what i've tried..

Answer (score 3):

Since it is ***not necessarily*** for you what RDBMS you are using, then let me assume that you are using MySQL, and you are looking for the customer that has the highest orders count:

```
SELECT 
  customers.customerid, 
  customers.name,
  COUNT(orders.orderid) AS Orderscount
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.customerid = orders.customerid 
GROUP BY customers.customerid, 
         customers.name
ORDER BY Orderscount DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: mistake in inner join. I think it should be `customers.customerid = orders.customerid`

Comment: @elhadi - For MySQL only, Yes. But, this not recommended to do so. In any other RDBMS this without a `GROUP BY` will got an error, and this is not what the SQL Standard dictate to follow, any column that is in the `SELECT` clause either must be included in a `GROUP BY` or included in an aggregate function. In case of MySQL it gets an arbitrary value for those `customerid` and `name` since they there is no `GROUP BY` clause but his is depeneds on an option in the database server.

Comment: @Kaf - Thanks, fixed now. I just copied it from the OP question

Comment: I did too but realised it was another issue in his query.

Answer (score 1):

For `SQL SERVER`;

```
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM (
    SELECT customers.customerid, customers.name, COUNT(*) AS CostumerCount 
    FROM customers INNER JOIN orders 
               ON customers.customerid=orders.customerid
    GROUP BY customers.customerid, customers.name 
) A
ORDER BY CostumerCount DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

your create table contain wrong syntax

try this

```
   CREATE TABLE customers(
   customerid INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   NAME CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   address CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   city CHAR(30)NOT NULL
   );


  CREATE TABLE orders(
  orderid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  customerid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL 
  );                               ^----remove comma ',' from here
```

and your query works good just replace `COUNT(customerid)` by `COUNT(customers.customerid)`

try it here

```
  SELECT customers.customerid, customers.name,orders.orderid, COUNT(customers.customerid) 
   AS CostumerCount 
   FROM customers 
   INNER JOIN orders 
  ON customers.customerid=orders.orderid;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT customers.customerid, customers.name, 
       orders.orderid, COUNT( orders.customerid ) AS CostumerCount
FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.customerid = orders.customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE cno = (
    SELECT cno FROM (
        SELECT count(*) as ordCount, cno 
        FROM ORDERS
        GROUP BY cno HAVING ordCount >= (
            SELECT max(ordCount) 
            FROM ( 
                SELECT count(*) as ordCount, cno 
                FROM ORDERS 
                GROUP BY cno
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the first answer because if you have more clients with the same number of orders **you will only get the first one!**

```
SELECT 
    customers.customerid, 
    customers.name,
    COUNT(orders.orderid) AS Orderscount
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.customerid = orders.customerid 
GROUP BY customers.customerid, 
         customers.name
HAVING Orderscount =  (       
    SELECT COUNT(id) AS Orderscount
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY customerid
    ORDER BY Orderscount DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```